# SPFX Extension not showing when deployed to office 365 (working in debug mode)

Tags: spfx

trying my luck here about this issue with spfx extension, thank you in advance

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/issues/63

Sorry in advance if this is against stack overflow rules (posting external forum)